# TypeError: contracts_build_directory is not a function

Tags: truffle

i am trying to make a simple React/Truffle project.
Truffle-config file:

```
module.exports = {
  contracts_build_directory: "./src/contracts",

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    }
 
  },


  mocha: {
  },

 
  compilers: {
    solc: {
     
    }
  }
};
```

The migrations work and json files get created. However, when i run truffle test

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

TypeError: contracts_build_directory is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\disst\Desktop\github\smart-contract\test\marketTest.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\disst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:390:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\disst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:387:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\disst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:961:10)
    at resolve (C:\Users\disst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\Test.js:149:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\disst\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\Test.js:148:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.1.59 (core: 5.1.59)
Node v10.16.0
```

I've been searching stackoverflow for a while but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `build_directory` instead of `contracts_build_directory`

Comment: There is only contracts_build_directory http://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#contracts_build_directory